# coloring and changing font of TOC using titletoc

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, titlesec, titletoc

I have to create the following TOC:
[image]

As for now, I was able to create this:

[image]

It was made using titletoc, namely I specified:

```
\titlecontents{section}[1em]{\normalfont \sffamily \bfseries}
{\thecontentslabel\enspace}
{}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\quad\contentspage}[\vskip 4pt]
```

Which is just one example I found and adjusted a bit. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out the documentation now, it seems overwhelming to me. So I'd be really glad if someone could help me to maintain the default layout of TOC and make numbering blue as well. By default layout I mean, which I get removing the above line of code:
[image]
That is exactly what I need but with section names in bold sans serif. Here is the whole file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titlesec, titletoc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont \Large \sffamily \bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont \large \sffamily \bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\titlecontents{section}[1em]{\normalfont \sffamily \bfseries}
{\thecontentslabel\enspace}
{}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\quad\contentspage}[\vskip 4pt]

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=black
}
\setcounter{section}{-1}
\title{\vspace{-6em}\textsf{\textbf{{\Huge Template}}}}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{Personal Data}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Donald Knuth about civilisation and productivity}
\subsection{What is this about?}
\section{Enumerations \& Tabulars \& Figures \& etc.}
\subsection{image in figure}
\subsection{tabular in table}
\subsection{enumerations}
\section{Mathematical Formulas}
\subsection*{equations}
As upcoming mathematician you should be able to type a formula as simple
as formula (1). The only difficulty should be constraint making use of \texttt{\textbackslash rlap}:
\begin{equation}
 \hspace{10000pt minus 1fil} \int_0^x \frac{1}{t+1}  \text{d}t = \ln (x+1) \qquad \qquad \text{for} \, x \in ] -1, \infty [ \hfilneg 
\end{equation}
\subsection{sets}
Don’t check the formula to be correct, just type it:
\[\forall x, M,N,O: (x \in M \lor (x \in N \land x \in O) \longleftrightarrow (M \cup N) \times (M \cup O) \ni (x,x))\]
\subsection{function definition}
$\varphi: \mathbb{C \times N \rightarrow R}, (z,m) \mapsto (\text{Re}(z+i))^m \cdot m$ is a simple function with $\varphi(2,2) = 8$.
\subsection{linear equations}
\section*{compiler}
This paper is compiled with pdf\LaTeX (August 5, 2021).
\end{document}
```